# Send data sensitive data to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Group" class="followbt" name="delete" onclick="deleteGroupDialog(' . $group_row['ngroup'] . ');">
```

The field 'ngroup' is the group number that i want to delete, and i am passing it to a javascript function that opens an jquery dialog window in order to ask if the user is certain of what is doing, the problem is that anyone can go on the browser and edit that number and go delete any group (that belongs to him).

I have already made a search about this but i didn't find anything, is there a way to pass the argument more securely?

PS: When i show the dialog window i don't want to reload the page a make a server request.

Comment: It's not the "man in the middle" that can change that argument, it's any person who can acess the "Inspect Element" in any browser...

Comment: There's no way to secure that, if you don't want the end user to have access to the data, don't send it to the end user, and if you don't want the end user to be able to delete anything on your server, validate the input from the end user.

Comment: there is no way the client side ...... must configure the server to access prohibited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your client-side code should **never** be the final word on what the user is allowed to do; that's the server's job. Client-side gatekeeping is purely there for UX, to guide the user to doing what they're allowed to do and guide them away from what they're not allowed to do.

Yes, the client can indeed go in and edit things, or even custom-craft HTTP messages to send to your server. That's why your server needs to be the gatekeeper. That way, you don't *care* if the user hand-edits the group number: If they're allowed to delete the group, they can delete it (through the UI or nefarious means); if they aren't, they can't, no matter how much client-side trickery they try.